# Simple linear regression and sampling

Tags: regression, sampling, regression-coefficients

I have a small dataset (60 elements) for which I fit a simple linear regression model, and obtain a small coefficient of determination ($R^2 = 3\%$). I'm a beginner in statistics so I'm trying to understand what would happen if I try to fit the model to different samples (of the same size) made up by different elements. On each fitted model $y_i = b_0 + b_1X_i + e_i$, the $b_0$ and $b_1$ coefficient will change, but since $R^2$ is likely low for any fitted model, it would be unlikely to obtain a better model by trying to fit different samples. Is this reasoning correct, or is there some other intuition to this? And what would happen in the contrary case ($R^2$ ~ 95% - 99%), is here also not worth to fit different models since the fitted model is very close to the theoretical one?

Comment: You should avoid the temptation to fit a bunch of different models with different variables just to get the $R^2$ up. If you've fit all the models that you think reasonably reflect what you think might be the real-world dynamics of what you're trying to model, and the $R^2$ is still low, then that's what it is.

Comment: What does the scatterplot of the data look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

elements = variables or samples?

firstly, you really shouldnt be cherry-picking elements from your data in order to seek the highest R^2, that is incorrect and quite possibly a misuse of statistics. Also, if we get a high or low R^2 for a given model built on a given subset of elements, that does not mean that you will get similar R^2 for a different model on a different subset of elements.